# i need to freeze the Top line in the table in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb7n5.png)[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I've written an html code for the table which is holding with child id and now I need to freeze the only header and scroll the data  if I apply styles it is not matching the lines that divide each column.

See my attached picture when I try to freeze the first line and it is already declared with certain widths but now it is compressing the widths.

Actually it looks like pic2 and if I am trying to do so it is becoming like pic1 can any one suggest me the best solution for this 
These not freezing the header because it is declared as single table.

[enter image description here][2]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb7n5.png)

Comment: Both images are the same...Also give us what you tried with your css or html. Maybe you need to apply a position fixed to first row?

Comment: i did this in css #child tbody{
    display:block;
    height:2000px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width:351%;
}

Comment: 2 images are exactly the same whats the problem?

Comment: i just edited them see now thank you

Comment: the first row is a `<tr>` or a `<th>` or what? give us the HTML code.

Comment: The first and second line are declared in  <tr>

Answer (score 0):

Try this css:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
}
thead, tbody, tr, td, th {
  display: block;
}
tr:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  clear: both;
}
tbody {
  height: 120px; /* Change this with your needs. */
  overflow-y: auto;
}
tbody td, thead th {
  width: 19.2%; /*If 5 columns then 19.2*/
  float: left;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4aazdqbc/2/

Comment: no it is not working when I am applying these css it displaying the header names one below the other

Comment: probably your css is messed up. try clearing your css.